# C# Interface class + inheritance VS pure Abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, interface, polymorphism, abstract

Is this OOP approach doomed to fail or is there some merit in this?

Before I understood abstract classes I was getting more or less the same benefits of code reuse by using an interface class + a regular class that implements certain methods of the interface. For example

```
public interface IMyService
{
    String Helloword1();
    String Helloword2();
    String Helloword3();
}

public class MyService
{
    public String Helloword1(){return "1";}
    public String Helloword2(){return "2";}
    //Helloworld3 is not here so I would be forced to provide implementation in any subclass
    //very similar to calling abstract on a method
}



public class SubClass1: MyService, IMyService
{

    public String Helloword3(){return "3";}

}


public class SubClass2: MyService, IMyService
{

    public new String Helloword2(){return "override method";}
    public String Helloword3(){return "3";}

}
```

Can anyone see of any advantage of doing this or is this really providing the same advantages as an abstract class?

Comment: Be aware that `SubClass2.Helloword2()` _hides_ `MyService.Helloword2()`, it does not _override_ it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone see of any advantage of doing this or is this really providing the same advantages as an abstract class?

There is a big disadvantage to doing this.  You allow people to subclass `MyService` *without* implementing `Helloword3`, since that's not part of the contract.

An abstract class would *enforce* that the type implements that member.  Here, you trust that the user will implement the "required" interface.

Comment: Of course, in the OPs case there's no real reason to prohibit the creation of the `MyService` type.  The reason that abstract classes can't be actually constructed isn't just an arbitrary restriction that isn't really adding value, but rather the restriction exists precisely because abstract classes are dependent on not-yet-implemented behavior, which is their real power.  Here the OP's class just inherently isn't abstract, in the conceptual sense, because there's no real reason why you *shouldn't* be able to construct an instance of it.

Answer (score 2):

In your example someone can actually construct an instance of `MyService` and use it without the use of the abstract method.

Honestly, there isn't even really any need to inherit form `MyService` in your two sub classes.  If `MyService` can be created concretely, that type can be composed, rather than inherited from.

The *real* value in an abstract class is where the concrete methods actually use the abstract methods.  Being able to write things like this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract Guid CreateUniqueIdentifier();
    public void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        Guid guid = CreateUniqueIdentifier();
        //do stuff with guid
    }
}
```

You cannot do something like this using your pattern; the concrete methods can never be dependent on the not-yet-implemented methods.